# <div> inside my XML tag raising problems for the XSLT transformation

Tags: xml, sharepoint, xslt

I am building a custom CQWP that is retrieving information from a SharePoint list. One of the fields retrieved is a "multiline text", therefore it contains  tags inside it.

When I apply my XSLT transformation, I receive an error message:

**`The character '<' cannot be used in an attribute value.`**

Do you know where it can come from ? Knowing that when I was using the default "OuterTemplate" there wasn't any problem with it.

Comment: if brian's solution below isn't sufficient, could you post some example xml and xsl to demonstrate the problem. I'm not sure if you have control over the xml content and whether you want it to contain embedded tags.

Answer (score 0):

you must encode all your nested xml. therefore you should

replace `<` with `&lt;`

and

`>` with `&gt;`  amongst many other encodings.

Comment: Did you mean "replace < with "&lt;" ?

Comment: no offence meant, just thought it might be good to fix it so as to not confuse others. Cheers.

Comment: @brian, I hope you don't mind, but I corrected the formatting, and made a correction indicated by your comment.

Comment: thank you flynn I gotta read the formatting docs one of these days.